# Deleted account showing up in network profile community list?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

I deleted my account from a community but it still shows up in my network profile community list. Is this list cleaned up at some point? Clicking the profile link results in a 404 (as expected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your network accounts list is not updated in real-time, but every so often. It usually fixes itself within a short amount of time (15 minutes is usually a good amount of time to wait for a lot of things around the network, but not everything runs on that interval).